# Android studio "do while" to choose the variable created in the MainActivity

Tags: android, do-while

I am trying to do automated android program to open a website listed in the variables. 
Please review the program shown in the photo.

[image]

My program is not successful due to the error in the highlighted area. I am not sure how can I combine the string.

Comment: What you are trying to do is passing string with concat i variable. You are not passing variable created above such as var1, var2 .... and so on

Comment: Try add these String in arrayList and iterate it. Do something like this

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of source code. Cut-n-paste the actual source code (with 4 leading blanks) into your post. Screenshots are not searchable or editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a string array -

```
String var[] = new String[4];
var[0]="www...";
var[1]="www...";
var[2]="www...";
var[3]="www...";
```

and then use

```
Intent browserIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(var[i]));
```

Comment: Thank guys, i have get the information to fix this issue :). i have choose the string array method to resolve this.                                                                                                String[] arrayOfString = {var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12};